# How to enable a child control of the disabled parent?

Tags: silverlight

I'm wondering if it's possible to make the child control enabled if its parent is disabled in Silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can set it as IsEnabled = true; but it will NEVER be anabled because the parent is no enabled